How to filter articles in Shopware 5 API by options defined in custom Property Groups?
I am trying to filter articles via the Shopware 5 API by values of property group options defined in a custom Property Group.
I can fetch the property group from:
https://<shop-url>/api/propertyGroups/id

and get an answer of the form:
{'data': {'id': 3,
  'name': '<property_group_name>',
  'position': 0,
  'comparable': False,
  'sortMode': 0,
  'options': [{'id': 3, 'name': 'prop1', 'filterable': True},
   {'id': 4, 'name': 'prop2', 'filterable': True},
   {'id': 5, 'name': 'prop3', 'filterable': False},
   {'id': 6, 'name': 'prop4', 'filterable': False}],
  'attribute': None},
 'success': True,
 'hbcom_article_faqs_sw53': True}

How can I use the property group options for filtering articles using the
https://<shop-url>/api/articles

endpoint?
I tried filtering using this pattern:
https://<shop-url>/api/articles?filter[0][property]=filterGroupId&filter[0][value]=3&filter[1][property]=prop1&filter[1][value]=<prop-value>

But the properties and values defined in the PropertyGroups don't seem to be reachable by this. Or am I missing some sort of additional nested structure here?
I am looking for a solution that implements the filtering either within the URL or as JSON-payload. I don't have any experience with PHP and am looking therefore looking for a solution that only uses the Shopware 5 API.
